# Socket.IO emit not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, game-development

I am currently building a game using Socket.IO and Javascript. I originally wanted to make a real-time multiplayer game, however, I ran into a problem really quick. I eventually gave up and moved to a turn-based game but the problem still didn't go away.

The problem is that the server (app.js) is not getting emits from the client (game.js). I've tried recreating the project, console.log, and search google to no avail.

App.js

```
require('./Database');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
serv.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000);
console.log("Server started.");

var SOCKET_LIST = {};


var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.id = Math.random();
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('signIn', function(data) {  // {username,password}

        Database.isValidPassword(data, function(res) {
            if (!res)
                return socket.emit('signInResponse', { success: false });
            Database.getPlayerProgress(data.username, function (progress) {


                socket.emit('signInResponse', {
                    success: true, username: data.username,
                    progress: progress
                });
            })
        });
    });
    socket.on('signUp', function(data) {

        Database.isUsernameTaken(data, function(res) {
            if (res) {
                socket.emit('signUpResponse', { success: false });
            } else {
                Database.addUser(data, function() {
                    socket.emit('signUpResponse', { success: true });
                });
            }
        });
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];

    });
    socket.on("findMatch", function(data) {
        console.log('test');  // ******* Not working ********

    });

});
```

Game.js

```
var socket = io("127.0.0.1:2000");

function findMatch(data) {
    socket.emit("findMatch", { socket: socket });
}
```

`FindMatch()` is called from the lobby "Find Match" Button. It is hooked up to an `onclick` listener.

Thank you. I would appreciate any help.

Edit: The connection, sign In, register, and disconnect emits DO work only custom ones I add later (findMatch for example) don't work

Comment: I changed your Java tag to JavaScript. Note that these two languages are *very* different, and there's no sense in attracting the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: Oh thanks, yeah I know it was a typo. I am knowledgable in Java too so I understand how that could be an issue. Thanks

Comment: Your client can connect to your server or not?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out though. I was trying to send the whole socket over instead of the id which caused a max stack error. Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: if you're gonna use sockets to login, signup, etc you need to `socket.to(userSocketId).emit(...)`.  Otherwise you're emitting those responses to anyone connected